# Database difference between drupal 6 and drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

I am a drupal learner.I don't know what is the database difference between drupal 6 and drupal 7? So can yoi just tell me whats the difference between them ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some contributed modules in Drupal6 which are included in Drupal7 as core modules like CCK module so some more tables are available by default. Also there are database structure changes & hence the data type of lots of fields like password have been changed.

For more details you can go here :- https://www.drupal.org/node/1329476